# Oil in expansion Bottle

Tags: overheating, daewoo, oil-cooler

Hi I live in Egypt and have a Daewoo Speranza M11 recently there was oil in the expansion bottle and the temperature light came on...the car did not overheat. The oil cooler was diagnosed and replaced ..we flushed it many times to clear the residual oil. Still it continued to overheat. The expansion bottle broke and it was replaced along with a new cap and a pipe leading from it.  The car is not losing engine oil there is no smoke and performance is good. Now it overheated again and oil in the expansion bottle...what do you suggest please. I don't trust the technicians here

EDIT: It was the oil coolant unit that was replaced and its a manual car...just as a sideline the air con also has decided not to work

Comment: Is it an auto or manual transmission?

Comment: Was it the engine oil cooler or transmission oil cooler that was replaced?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Its manual and the engine oil cooler was replaced